# Possible Bug in VS2015 Code snippets after Update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

I recently updated my VS2015 to Update 2. Since then the code snippets feature isn't working correctly. I don't know if it is a settings that changed or it's an actual bug.
When I try to add a region snippet to surround code I get:

```
#pragma region MyRegion
```

and

```
#pragma endregion
```

This bug appears also in the try snippet i get:

```
catch (const std::exception&)
```

instead of the regular

```
catch(Exception ex)
```

[image: try snippet]
[image: try snippet]
[image: region snippet]
[image: region snippet]

Anyone came accross this issue? or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I remember the "region" problem. The problem is fixed now in Update 3.

Comment: Nevertheless I think the [msdn community](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home) is a better place to ask questions like this.